# GJK algorithm in case of circle and polygon?

Tags: collision-detection

I wonder if it's possible to modify GJK so I can use it to detect collision between circle and n points polygon. 
I implemented for polygon and polygon before, and I tried modifying the support function (to get furthest point of a circle), but apparently, this results in infinite loop. 
Is this possible to do? do I need to change other thing than the support function? (because I don't see any)

Comment: I think it's definitely possible, since my 3D GJK implementation can handle sphere shape, among a few others. It does, however, on very rare occasions, seem to get stuck in an infinite loop.
I tested a few times and it seemed to determine collision within up to 20 iterations. So I just modified it to return no collision  if number of iterations reached 100. It's not elegant but it was good enough for the purpose intended then. I saw some blog post about GJK's numerical instability which causes infinite loops, but I haven't been able to find it again.